# Flutter: Making Podfiles work

Tags: ios, cocoapods, flutter

I'm trying to add the Facebook SDK to one of my Flutter projects. In a regular Podfile, it'd look something like this:

```
  # Pods for facebooklogintest

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’
```

With "facebooklogintest" being the name of my project. The Podfile in Flutter projects looks a bit different. Is it correct to add the pod files under "# Pods for Runner"?

```
  # Pods for Runner

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to install it as shown above:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Please set FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR to the directory containing Flutter.framework.
```

Where and to where should I point this file to get rid of this error?

Comment: Please run flutter run -v and post the logs showing the full output  from CocoaPods. You may need to pod repo update.

Comment: @CollinJackson Totally forgot I wasn't running on my own machine. Flutter hadn't been installed yet... But about the podfile itself. Where should I add the facebook pod lines?

Comment: Hm installed the Flutter and added the variable path etc but still getting the same error when running pod install...

Comment: Flutter run automatically installed these dependencies for me. And for some reason that did work. Weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
def fbPods
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’
end

target 'facebooklogintest' do
    fbPods
end

target 'Runner' do
    fbPods
end
```

**Run this command**

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

Comment: Thank you, but would it be wrong to just add the facebook pod lines under "Pods for Runner" as shown in the question?

Comment: yes you can as same as question but both target have same pod so i have defined at one place .

Answer (score 0):

In bash_profile,
export FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR=/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios

source ~/.bash_profile

In iOS folder,
pod install